Help with an $\varepsilon$ ,$\delta$ proof for a 2 variable limit
Hey there I was asked to prove the following limit by using the definiton:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac{2x+y}{1+x^2+y^3}   = 1
\end{equation}
My attempt so far: Let  $\varepsilon >0$. Assume: $0<||(x,y)-(1,1)||<\delta  ~\iff~  0<\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}<\delta $
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{2x+y}{1+x^2+y^3}-1\right| = \left|\frac{2x+y-1-x^2-y^3}{1+x^2+y^3}\right| 
= \left|\frac{(x-1)^2+y^2(y-1)}{1+x^2+y^3}\right| \leq \left|(x-1)^2+y^2(y-1)\right|
\end{equation}
Because $y$ is close to 1 so $1+x^2+y^3>1.
How can I proceed? I know that since $x$ is close to 1 I can estimate $(x-1)^2\leq|x-1|$ but I still cannot get rid of the $y^2$ term, can I?

$|(x-1)^2+y^2(y-1)|\le|x-1|^2+|y|^2|y-1|$
Now choose $\begin{cases}|x-1|<\delta\\|y-1|<\delta\end{cases}\quad$ with $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon)$
In particular $|x-1|^2<\delta\times\delta<1\times\varepsilon=\varepsilon$
And $|y-1|<1\iff -1\le y-1\le 1\iff 0\le y\le 2$
Therefore $|y|^2|y-1|\le 4\times\delta<4\varepsilon$
And you are good with $5\varepsilon$, you can eventually refine with $\delta=\min(1,\frac \varepsilon 5)$ but this is not really necessary.

Thank u for the quick answer I knew it was such an easy thing but I was stuck haha
